# Does Python have something like LINQ to XML

Tags: python

I need to parse XML file and put results on HTML form, but I am new to Python. Does Python 2.7 have something like LINQ to XML from C# or any good library for XML can suggest me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085337/linq-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Pynq – Python Language Integrated Query https://github.com/heynemann/pynq/wiki

I'm sure though if Pynq will be sufficient for you, although it does implement exprenssion trees in Python just like LINQ does for C#.

For an easy way to access XML in Python, you could check out BeautifulSoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html). Note: for XML processing: use `BeautifulStoneSoup` for XML processing.

A simple example: "find first three a tags"

```
soup.findAll('p', limit=3)
```

For a more comprehensive selection of XML libraries for Python, please see ["PythonXml"](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml) in PythonInfo Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [lxml](http://lxml.de), more specifically the combination of:

- the ElementTree interface: an easier xml model/api than DOM, much like the XDocument and XElement classes (attributes and text are even simpler because they are not separate "nodes", which may look strange at first if you're working with "mixed content" models a lot and you're used to DOM interfaces)
- The [E-factory](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-e-factory) of lxml.builder (like "functional construction" in LINQ to XML, but even better ;-))
- python's built-in list comprehensions and generator expressions, which can get you very close to the LINQ query syntax (without looking like SQL however ;-))

... will get you a very similar experience. (having played with LINQ to XML in .NET as well: I much prefer working python and lxml)

Another remark: lxml has some good support for html (even ill-formed) as well, including facilities for [filling out html forms](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#form-filling-example) (I'm not sure if that is what you meant with "put results on html form" however)

Answer (score 0):

The most featured XML library in python is lxml http://lxml.de but it doesn't support LINQ interface, as I know.

You can use ElementTree interface http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-elementtree-class

or XPAth selectors http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath

or CSS selectors http://lxml.de/cssselect.html

for data extraction from XML.